# Retrieving Data / Datum In A '< List >'

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop, linq-to-sql

I have a list:

```
     public List<View_Group> GetGroupID_FromEmpNo(Int16 x)
    {
        List<View_Group> query = (from a in contxt.View_Group
                                  where a.EmpNo == x
                                  select new View_Group 
                                 { 
                                 id = a.id,
                                 EmpNo = a.EmpNo 
                                 }).ToList();
        return query.ToList();
    }
```

a.EmpNo column have two same values, same Employee numbers (2884). If I can simply retrieve the first value using .FirstOrDefault() to get the first a.id, how do I retrieve the last value of a.id using the same Employee number (2884)?

I'm thinking using foreach loop through an array but this is a list and I am sort of new to looping, arrays, especially lists in C#.

Regards

Comment: Or do you want your method to retrieve one EmpNo, the smallest id for this EmpNo and the biggest id for this EmpNo ? Not really clear...

Comment: Hmmm it says "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int16 LastOrDefault[Int16](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int16])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression." for LastOrDefault() for me.

Comment: I want to know learn how to retrieve either, in this way, I can practice looping through arrays. :) @Raphael Althaus

Comment: This whole function will return a list with two `View_Group` values, correct? Which of these two do you want to select? The one with the highest id, or by some other property?

Comment: @Niklas Yes I want to select the highest id, that's the main goal. Although I'd like to learn how to select ANY value I want if there are 3 data in the column with the same EmpNo. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `orderby descending` and then `FirstOrDefault()`

```
var lastitem = (from a in contxt.View_Group
     where a.EmpNo == x
     orderby a.id descending
     select new View_Group 
     { 
       id = a.id,
       EmpNo = a.EmpNo 
     }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Goal is met. Thanks Amar! :)

Comment: This could be simplified to: `var lastitem = (from a in contxt.View_Group where a.EmpNo == x orderby a.id descending select a).FirstOrDefault();`